# Matrix multiplication by it's transpose returning zeros matrix?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm multiplying a matrix by it's transpose and I'm getting a zeros matrix.

I am multiplying other matrices and not having any problems. I've tried this both with `cvMul` and `cvMulTransposed` and always get a zeros matrix, which is different from the expected result.

Code:

```
  CvMat *test = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F);
  CvMat *test2 = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F);
  for(NSInteger row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (NSInteger column = 0; column < 3; column++) {
      double value = 0.0f;
      if (row == column) {
        switch(row+column) {
          case 0:
            value = 16.815826;
            break;
          case 2:
            value = 1.492630;
            break;
        }
      }
      cvSetReal2D(test, row, column, value);
      cvSetReal2D(test2, row, column, value);
    }
  }

  [self printCvMat:test];
  [self printCvMat:test2];

  CvMat *testResult = cvCreateMat(test->rows, test2->cols, CV_64F);
  cvMul(test, test2, testResult, 0.0f); 
  [self printCvMat:testResult];
```

The output:

```
Printing Matrix:
16.815826 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 1.492630 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
Printing Matrix:
16.815826 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 1.492630 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Printing Matrix:
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

It should be:

```
282.772   0.000   0.000
  0.000   2.228   0.000
  0.000   0.000   0.000
```

Comment: I have never faced this error, but this may help, as you haven't mentioned your openCV version: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/6750

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvmul):

> The function **`multiply`** calculates the per-element product of two arrays:
>
> dst(I) = saturate(scale • src1(I) • src2(I))

You're passing a `0` for the scale.

Comment: Or, it could be that as well :) +1